# sorting data in php/ mysql like excel sorting

Tags: php, sql, excel

I want to select some data with alphanumeric format and sort them using `ORDER BY` in a mysql query and exporting them as an excel file. When sorted data in excel standard sorting, result not same as mysql sorting.
What can I do?
My query is simple `order by(col)`
My data are like below:

[data sort by database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P71Aq.png)
and 
[data sorted in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05epJ.png)
How can I sorting like excel in `php` or `sql` query?

How can I select data from database like Excel

these are Excel sorting

```
39<br>
41<br>
42<br>
45<br>
46<br>
47<br>
111<br>
123<br>
545<br>
KP-67-87<br>
KP-62-82<br>
KP-65-85<br>
KP-59-77<br>
KP-44-61<br>
KP-15-20<br>
KP-43-60<br>
```

and these are sql sorting

```
45 <br>
46<br>
47<br>
5<br>
545<br>
6<br>
KP-103-124<br>
KP-104-125<br>
KP-116-139<br>
KP-11715-11772<br>
KP-1218-1365<br>
KP-146-205<br>
KP-147-206<br>
KP-15-20<br>
KP-154-214<br>
```

Comment: SQL data has a specified type.  Hence, it is known whether the values are strings or numeric or date/times.  This makes database tables different from Excel.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? Worded as it is, it's quite hard to understand this question.

Comment: i attached two image from my data ,

Comment: The "data exporting from database" does not seem to be sorted at all. How do you want the data to be sorted?

Comment: You've posted the same data for both the database and Excel in your question. Please also show us the order you want the data to be shown in.

Comment: yes , sorry ,i edited with simple order by query

Comment: As Gordon Linoff mentioned, a database cannot mix numeric and text values in one field. Thats why the DB-order is in text manner only. Excel can mix numeric and text values in one column. Thats why Excel sorts numbers in numeric manner and text in text manner. A well known problem which will be found with search keywords `sql sort text as number`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
order by col * 1, col
```